# update git mv index

Tags: git, merge

**Git doesn't track renames**

I had a file `dir1/some.class`.
I copied it as `dir2/some.class` and commited + pushed.
Some weeks later, I've removed the `dir1` version.

Can I teach git to act as if it was a move, rather than a new file?
So all changes to `dir1/some.class` that I will merge from other branches will actually merge into `dir2/some.class` ?

I tried with

```
git checkout mybranch
git config merge.renameLimit 100
git merge --no-ff -X rename-threshold=80 master
git config --unset merge.renameLimit
```

some of the files got merged. But some don't. Especially what I'm missing, is a git log ability, to see changes to `dir2/class` originated at the past as `dir1/class`, but that doesn't happen.

[image]

**What actualy helped me was**

Low renaming threshold (10% similarity to consider a file renamed)
Large merge.renameLimit ( consumes a lot of ram during merge )

```
 git checkout mybranch
 git config merge.renameLimit 999999
 git merge --no-ff -X rename-threshold=10 -Xignore-space-change master
 git config --unset merge.renameLimit
```

Also check out the answer marked below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this: in the branch you're merging in, rename `dir1` to `dir2` (you can do this on a new, temporary branch if you want).  Then merge that into your main branch.

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll definitely give it a try. Too bad there are a lot of renames in the project and they are not that straight to use a renaming script. Although I afraid renaming it on a new branch will bring me to the same situation when I'll try to merge all changes back to master ;)

Comment: That's probably the right answer, therefore I'll mark it as correct, but what actually helped me is decreasing the rename-threshold and increasing the renameLimit because I had a lot of renames after refactoring, without any concrete structure.